# Is my deduction about the import statements right?

Tags: java

I'm talking about the import statements at the top.

```
Eg: 
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

So, can I just say that:

> Anything that starts with a lower-case letter (java, util, javax and swing here) is always a package and everything that begins with an uppercase is always a Class (which may be followed by an Inner class in some cases).

Comment: You need to further explain your question? It seems you are asking if there is a way for your coding environment to know what imports are packages and what imports are classes. However, it is not clear. If what I assume to be your question is indeed what you are asking, Eclipse has an intelligent system that auto-completes import statements if you want to complete import statements faster. However, as I have already said, your question is vauge and needs to be further explained

Comment: It's not about Eclipse or any other IDE. It's about me looking at some code and figuring out by myself (I know I don't need to, but still)>

Comment: I suggest you select the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

That's not necessarily true, as you can create classes starting with lowercase letters and packages starting with uppercase letters, but it is generally good practice to follow the [Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

These dictate that what you said should be true.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) on the Oracle site, you will see that package names should, by convention, start with a lower-case letter and class names, method names, interface names, and others, should, by convention, start with an upper-case letter. This allows you and anyone who reads your code later to know what statements are imports of packages (although the `import` keyword makes it obvious) and where you have classes and methods. It also makes your code appear neater aiding readability. You could say that it allows your one's brain to compile what it is reading faster. For example, seeing a constant value in all caps like `static final int MIN_WIDTH = 4;` makes it much easier to understand what is going on.

I would like to point out that the information is relatively easy to find via google and there are other questions on Stackoverflow that would have the answer to your question. Please do your research in the future.

Comment: Method names... upper case?

Comment: @pbabcdefp with method names, if there are more than one word, subsequent words begin with an uppercase letter e.g. `scanner.equalsIgnoreCase(String str);`

Answer (score 0):

If the naming conventions have been followed and we are not talking about static imports, then what you say is true.

With static imports you can import constants and methods as well.

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
```